# How do I check that the value of a param is a number in a certain range

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to write a test suite for a method that sends a POST request with a parameter 'target' that has to be between 0 and 10

My Ruby class:

```
class ClassName
  before_action :must_have_valid_target

  def create
     target = params[:target]
     . . .
  end 

  def must_have_valid_target
    return if params.key?(:target)
    error_response(422, 'error message')
  end
end
```

My Rspec

```
it 'cannot create request with negative target' do
  post(:create, {target: -1})
  assert_response(422) # actual result is: Expected 422, Actual 200
end
```

I tried:

```
def must_have_valid_target
  valid = params[:target].between?(0,10)
end
```

but this does not work. How do I check that the symbol has a value between the range so I can give the correct response afterwards?

This is not homework, I am trying to add additional tests to the codebase at my workplace but I am still very new to RSpec and Ruby.

Comment: Is `params[:target]` a number or a string?

Comment: `before_action` is not a hook that is added to `Object` so it has no bearing in `Class` as a class instance method (honestly if this is your actual code this would raise a `NoMethodError`) please post something a bit more valid/reproducible.

Comment: @engineersmnky even more, `before_action` is not something that exists in [tag:ruby] by any mean.

Comment: I wonder if this question is actually about Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params[:target]` is a string, cast to integer prior to the comparison,

```
def must_have_valid_target
  params[:target].present? && params[:target].to_i.between?(0,10)
end
```

Comment: This make the lack of `params[:target]` valid as well since `nil.to_i #=> 0`

Comment: Good point @engineersmnky I updated my answer for a presence check

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I didn't think to check for the parameter to be present and it was breaking everything

Comment: Great @1mpe7us - good to hear. Please accept my answer if you are good to go.